# TensorFlow convolution huge loss function values

Tags: python, tensorflow, loss

I've been playing around with the TensorFlow Cifar10 demo (https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/tutorials/deep_cnn/index.html#convolutional-neural-networks), and I ran into the following funny-looking output when implementing AlexNet (227x227 images) with batch size 1 inside Google's demo code:

`2016-01-12 13:19:28.042847: step 0, loss = 208.40 (0.0 examples/sec; 28.081 sec/batch)
2016-01-12 13:19:37.991020: step 10, loss = 106981280.00 (2.3 examples/sec; 0.440 sec/batch)
2016-01-12 13:19:42.422207: step 20, loss = 318574152697306415104.00 (2.2 examples/sec; 0.446 sec/batch)
2016-01-12 13:19:46.824720: step 30, loss = 316031624417051148288.00 (2.3 examples/sec; 0.439 sec/batch)
2016-01-12 13:19:51.238086: step 40, loss = 313512247453630332928.00 (2.2 examples/sec; 0.449 sec/batch)
2016-01-12 13:19:55.676777: step 50, loss = 311012714476067618816.00 (2.3 examples/sec; 0.436 sec/batch)
2016-01-12 13:20:00.056848: step 60, loss = 308535664312269668352.00 (2.3 examples/sec; 0.438 sec/batch)
2016-01-12 13:20:04.442751: step 70, loss = 306075115618981380096.00 (2.3 examples/sec; 0.436 sec/batch)`

Why is the loss value so huge after a few batches? The network also does not seem to converge to anything above random (I'm training it to determine how good the color balance is in a photo). I will only post the code that I changed - with the exception of small directory name changes and image size parameters, as the rest is available on the TensorFlow website. Let me know if you need to see more of the code though.

```
def inference(images):
  """Build the CIFAR-10 model.

  Args:
    images: Images returned from distorted_inputs() or inputs().

  Returns:
    Logits.
  """
  # We instantiate all variables using tf.get_variable() instead of
  # tf.Variable() in order to share variables across multiple GPU training runs.
  # If we only ran this model on a single GPU, we could simplify this function
  # by replacing all instances of tf.get_variable() with tf.Variable().
  #
  # conv1
  with tf.variable_scope('conv1') as scope:
    kernel = _variable_with_weight_decay('weights', shape=[11, 11, 3, 96],
      stddev=1e-4, wd=0.0)
    conv = tf.nn.conv2d(images, kernel, [1, 4, 4, 1], padding='SAME')
    biases = _variable_on_cpu('biases', [96], tf.constant_initializer(0.0))
    bias = tf.nn.bias_add(conv, biases)
    conv1 = tf.nn.relu6(bias, name=scope.name)
    _activation_summary(conv1)

  # norm1
  norm1 = tf.nn.lrn(conv1, 4, bias=1.0, alpha=0.0001, beta=0.75,
    name='norm1')

  # pool1
  pool1 = tf.nn.max_pool(norm1, ksize=[1, 3, 3, 1], strides=[1, 2, 2, 1],
    padding='SAME', name='pool1')

  # conv2
  with tf.variable_scope('conv2') as scope:
    kernel = _variable_with_weight_decay('weights', shape=[5, 5, 96, 256],
      stddev=1e-4, wd=0.0)
    conv = tf.nn.conv2d(pool1, kernel, [1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
    biases = _variable_on_cpu('biases', [256], tf.constant_initializer(0.1))
    bias = tf.nn.bias_add(conv, biases)
    conv2 = tf.nn.relu6(bias, name=scope.name)
    _activation_summary(conv2)

  # norm2
  norm2 = tf.nn.lrn(conv2, 4, bias=1.0, alpha=0.0001, beta=0.75,
    name='norm2')

  # pool2
  pool2 = tf.nn.max_pool(norm2, ksize=[1, 3, 3, 1],
    strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME', name='pool2')

  # conv3
  with tf.variable_scope('conv3') as scope:
    kernel = _variable_with_weight_decay('weights', shape=[3, 3, 256, 384],
      stddev=1e-4, wd=0.0)
    conv = tf.nn.conv2d(pool2, kernel, [1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
    biases = _variable_on_cpu('biases', [384], tf.constant_initializer(0.1))
    bias = tf.nn.bias_add(conv, biases)
    conv3 = tf.nn.relu6(bias, name=scope.name)
    _activation_summary(conv3)

  # conv4
  with tf.variable_scope('conv4') as scope:
    kernel = _variable_with_weight_decay('weights', shape=[3, 3, 384, 384],
      stddev=1e-4, wd=0.0)
    conv = tf.nn.conv2d(conv3, kernel, [1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
    biases = _variable_on_cpu('biases', [384], tf.constant_initializer(0.1))
    bias = tf.nn.bias_add(conv, biases)
    conv4 = tf.nn.relu6(bias, name=scope.name)
    _activation_summary(conv4)

  # conv5
  with tf.variable_scope('conv5') as scope:
    kernel = _variable_with_weight_decay('weights', shape=[3, 3, 384, 256],
      stddev=1e-4, wd=0.0)
    conv = tf.nn.conv2d(conv4, kernel, [1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
    biases = _variable_on_cpu('biases', [256], tf.constant_initializer(0.1))
    bias = tf.nn.bias_add(conv, biases)
    conv5 = tf.nn.relu6(bias, name=scope.name)
    _activation_summary(conv5)  

  # pool5
  pool5 = tf.nn.max_pool(conv5, ksize=[1, 3, 3, 1],
    strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME', name='pool5')


  # local6
  with tf.variable_scope('local6') as scope:
    # Move everything into depth so we can perform a single matrix multiply.
    dim = 1
    for d in pool5.get_shape()[1:].as_list():
      dim *= d
    reshape = tf.reshape(pool5, [FLAGS.batch_size, dim])

    weights = _variable_with_weight_decay('weights', shape=[dim, 4096],
      stddev=0.04, wd=0.004)
    biases = _variable_on_cpu('biases', [4096], tf.constant_initializer(0.1))
    local6 = tf.nn.relu_layer(reshape, weights, biases, name=scope.name)
    _activation_summary(local6)

  # local7
  with tf.variable_scope('local7') as scope:
    weights = _variable_with_weight_decay('weights', shape=[4096, 4096],
      stddev=0.04, wd=0.004)
    biases = _variable_on_cpu('biases', [4096], tf.constant_initializer(0.1))
    local7 = tf.nn.relu_layer(local6, weights, biases, name=scope.name)
    _activation_summary(local7)

  # softmax, i.e. softmax(WX + b)
  with tf.variable_scope('softmax_linear') as scope:
    weights = _variable_with_weight_decay('weights', [4096, NUM_CLASSES],
      stddev=1/4096.0, wd=0.0)
    biases = _variable_on_cpu('biases', [NUM_CLASSES],
      tf.constant_initializer(0.0))
    softmax_linear = tf.nn.xw_plus_b(local7, weights, biases, name=scope.name)
    _activation_summary(softmax_linear)

  return softmax_linear
```

Comment: What learning rate are you using?

Comment: 0.1 initial learning rate, does not decay for the first 300 epochs.

Comment: How many output classes do you have?

Comment: Cross entropy error can indeed grow arbitrarily large. You may want to try reducing the learning rate to, say, 0.01, and see if this happens.

Comment: @mathetes I have two output classes (good color balance, bad color balance). And changing the learning rate did reduce the cross entropy error by a lot, thank you.